Accessing Pose_Assets
I am using Blender v3.5.1 and need to run a function that sets the frame number and apply a pose_asset(by name) to it then keyframe it.
My problem is in accessing the pose_asset by name with a python script.
When done manually, with a mouse, the info wondow shows that the pose_asset is selected by index. The problem with index is that I have many poses for many objects in the Assets folder and consequently many index numbers. That is why access via name would be a better solution.
Has anyone successfully used python to apply a pose_asset by name?
